# How do we define width of Grid Column in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm creating a grid with tailwind CSS but I'm stuck with resizing the grid division. Below is the code I have tried.

```
<div class="grid grid-col-2 gap-1">
<span class="bg-green-500">Item 1 </span>
<span class="bg-green-500">Item 2 </span>
</div>
```

This will result like this and that's fine for me what I want is that the Item 1 col should be 50px and Item 2 col should be auto width.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="grid grid-cols-[50px_auto] gap-1">
<span class="bg-green-500">Item 1 </span>
<span class="bg-green-500">Item 2 </span>
</div>
```

Try this code

And there is a typo in your code instead of `grid-col` it should be `grid-cols`

Answer (score 1):

##### For this use case, I recommend you to use `flex`

Use `width` of `50px` to your desired div and use `flex-1` to the sibling to have `auto width`

```
<div class="flex">
  <span class="w-[50px] bg-amber-500">Item 1 </span>
  <span class="flex-1 bg-cyan-400">Item 2 </span>
</div>
```

#### Output:

[image]

---

##### If you want to do this anyways in the `grid`,then try the following attribute values with the `grid-cols`

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-[50px_auto] gap-1">
  <span class="bg-amber-500">Item 1 </span>
  <span class="bg-cyan-500">Item 2 </span>
</div>
```

#### Output:

[image]